# visual c++ File::Exists not working

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, xml-parsing, visual-studio-2013

Excuse me For This Novice Question.

I am using visual studio ultimate in win7.
Currently Trying to read XML file. My xml file location is C:\Users\Sael\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hotel_Management\Debug\temp\app.xml.

But when I am debugging my app.exe I got this message 'The file C:\Users\Sael\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hotel_Management\Debug\temp\app.xml was not found'
Actually my xml file is exists. Can anyone help?

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Xml;
```

......

```
     XmlDocument ^ docVideo = gcnew XmlDocument;
             String ^ strFilename = L"C:\Users\Sael\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hotel_Management\Debug\temp\app.xml";

             if (File::Exists(strFilename))
             {
                 char *path = NULL;
                 size_t size;
                 path = getcwd(path, size);
                 MessageBox(NULL, pwd, pwd, 0);

                 docVideo->Load(strFilename);
                 XmlElement ^ elm = docVideo->DocumentElement;
                 XmlNodeList ^ lstVideos = elm->ChildNodes;

                 MessageBox::Show("The root element contains " +
                     lstVideos->Count + L" nodes");
                 //txtDocument->Text = elm->InnerText;
             }
             else
                 MessageBox::Show(L"The file " + strFilename + L" was not found");
```

Comment: This is Managed C++, why have you tagged it C++?

Comment: This is not C++. Please re-tag the question C++/CLI or C++/CX as appropriate.

Comment: I have tagged as visual c++, winforms.